# Was unable to turn lazy loading off in VB in EF6

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

VS2013, code first EF6, VB

Elsewhere on SO I found a post that led me to add this to my Context class:

```
Public Sub New()
  Me.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = False
End Sub
```

However, in order to load a secondary table into my context for a view to find data to list in a For Each loop I had to add:

```
Dim myQuery = db.Questions.Include("PossibleAnswers").Where(Function(x) x.QuestionID = 6).Single()
```

Without that query in one form or another, my view does not find any data in the property 'PossibleAnswers' and nothing is displayed during the For Each loop.  But with the query above, the For Each finds the PossibleAnswers data.

I checked the value of

```
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled
```

just before my view was called and it was false.  But I still had to make a query with the Include() method to force the data to be brought into the context.

This is the full definition of the table in question:

```
Public Class Question
  Public Enum qType
    TrueFalse
    MultipleChoice
    ShortAnswer
  End Enum
  Public Property QuestionID As Integer
  Public Property Text As String
  Public Property Type As qType
  Public Property PossibleAnswers As New List(Of qAnswer)
  Public Property UsedBySurveys As New List(Of qSurvey)
End Class
```

Can anybody suggest what I may not be understanding about this?

Thanks.

Best Regards,
Alan

Answer (score 0):

If you want all results from your context to automatically load the navigation properties, you should remove the Me.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = False line from your context class.

You can also explicitly set lazy loading to false for an instance of your context: ie.

```
Using db As New MyContext
    db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = True
    Dim myQuery = db.Questions.Where(Function(x) x.QuestionID = 6).Single()
End Using
```

With Lazy Loading set to false, you have to explicitly tell the EF to include navigation properties along with the result set. You do that by using the .Include function (as you did). Calling the .Include function is called Eager Loading.

If you set the lazy loading property to true, the navigation properties will be pulled back from the database automatically. Here's a quick run down of Lazy Loading from MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456846(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I studied the link you provided. So it seems in my initial post above that I specified exactly the opposite of what I wanted, yes? In order for all data to auto-load you (& your link above) are telling me to set LazyLoadingEnabled = True.  So is the idea that it's called Lazy because "I was lazy about specifying" so it loads everything to be sure?  Now, in your example you have an .Include, but because ...Lazy = True; wouldn't I get PossibleAnswers without that particular .Include in your example?  Or am I still missing something?

Comment: Correct, your initial post specified the opposite of what you wanted. I like the "I was lazy about specifying" phrase, that's just what it does. It will load everything. The .Include from my example above is not needed. I copied your code to use in my example and forgot to exclude that. I edited  my example to take that out.